# Why use IS DISTINCT FROM - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the best use of this function in `Postgres` `IS DISTINCT FROM`, auditioning got the same result using `COALESCE` but in less time , following the test :

````
SELECT COUNT(P.id)

FROM produto P
  INNER JOIN cliente CL ON P.id_cliente = CL.id_cliente

WHERE 
  COALESCE(CL.tp_pessoa,'') <> 'JURIDICA' -- test with COALESCE, average 610 ms

  (CL.tp_pessoa <> 'JURIDICA' OR CL.tp_pessoa IS NULL) -- test with OR, average 668 ms

  CL.tp_pessoa IS DISTINCT FROM 'JURIDICA' -- test with IS DISTINCT FROM, average 667 ms

  OUTRO TESTE:

  COALESCE(CL.tp_pessoa,'') <> COALESCE(P.observacao,'') -- test with IS DISTINCT FROM, average 940 ms

  CL.tp_pessoa IS DISTINCT FROM P.observacao -- test with ```IS DISTINCT FROM```, average 930 ms, a little beter here
````

Its have lower performance and is a function that is not found in other DBs such as `SQL Server` , another reason to not use it .

Doing another test, where both criteria can be `NULL` , the `IS DISTINCT FROM` had a slight advantage , this would be its use , where more it applies ?

Edit:

Like @hvd said, `IS DISTINCT FROM` is part of `ANSI SQL`, also, the result of `COALESCE(CL.tp_pessoa,'') <> COALESCE(P.observacao,'')` is not the same of `CL.tp_pessoa IS DISTINCT FROM P.observacao`.

Comment: "and is a function that is not found in other DBs" -- True, but worth mentioning is that it is part of ANSI SQL, so the fact that other DBs don't include it is something others might see as a problem with those other DBs.

Comment: @hvd, @Gordon Linoff, @Bacon Bits, @Gabriel's Messanger: For my tests , I'm comparing what ```tp_pessoa``` should NOT be , using ```index``` help in this case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, it is convenient.  Second, you need to run tests on larger amounts of data.  A lot can happen on a database server in a second, so small changes in hundredths of a second are not necessarily indicative of overall performance.

On the positive side, I think Postgres will use an index for `is distinct from`.  I don't think an index will necessarily be used for all the alternatives.

Comment: Did further tests on a larger bank, on my local machine , so no software competition , and the difference was minimal again 2230 - 2240 ms , then performance is no problem

Answer (score 13):

The performance differences you've seen are minimal. Focus on correctness.

You give an example

```
COALESCE(CL.tp_pessoa,'') <> COALESCE(P.observacao,'')
```

versus

```
CL.tp_pessoa IS DISTINCT FROM P.observacao
```

If `CL.tp_pessoa` is `NULL`, and `P.observacao` is `''`, then the first comparison treats them as equal, whereas the second comparison treats them as unequal.

So use the first version if you want to compare them as equal, and the second version if you want to compare them as unequal.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with `COALESCE()` is that it makes the clause non-[SARGable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217983/72776). That will impact performance because indexes can't be used.

The problem with `(CL.tp_pessoa <> 'JURIDICA' OR CL.tp_pessoa IS NULL)` is that it's verbose, especially when you're looking at comparing two fields that might both be NULL:

```
(CL.tp_pessoa <> CL2.tp_pessoa 
    OR (CL.tp_pessoa IS NOT NULL AND CL2.tp_pessoa IS NULL) 
    OR (CL.tp_pessoa IS NULL AND CL2.tp_pessoa IS NOT NULL))
```

If you're doing an UPDATE to merge a temp table with your base table and they share 30 fields and you only want to update when at least one of the fields is different and any of the 29 non-key fields can be NULL... you can understand how much of a pain it can be to write the query.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a index on `column1` like `CREATE INDEX "index_name" ON  table1 USING btree (column1);` then in case of `IS DISTINCT FROM`  sql engine can use thet index. With `COALESCE` it can't.