# NULL values in coulmn are not comparable via equality operator in POSTGRES SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I wanted to get records from a single table where `end_date` column values are same of particular `so_line_id` and state value. Due to that I do self join from table itself

| id | so_line_id | field | value | end_date | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4040 | product | submitted | 2022-02-07 02:03:40 | 2022-02-07 02:03:30 |
| 2 | 4040 | product | pending_fulfillment | 2022-02-07 03:03:10 | 2022-02-07 02:03:40 |
| 3 | 4040 | product | active | NULL | 2022-02-07 03:03:10 |
| 4 | 4040 | product | active | NULL | 2022-02-15 06:20:10 |

I tried to get result via query mention below
`select * from product_history h1 join product_history h2 on h1.so_line_id = h2.so_line_id and h2.id != h1.id and h1.end_date = h2.end_date where h1.so_line_id = 4040;`

Above completely works fine when we have datetime values instead of NULL.

Comment: If you want to include "NULL equals to NULL", you can do `col1 is not distinct from col2`.

Comment: @nbk Yes it is but didn't find it. I understand the issue from blog https://www.percona.com/blog/handling-null-values-in-postgresql/

Comment: Null Handling is in every database equal as it is defined as stadard and every Database system has its own NULL safe equal handling, so you would find actually many many threads for that.

Comment: nukll safe comparison on Posthgres https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828329/why-use-is-distinct-from-postgres

Answer (score 0):

We need to understand that NULL means no value in PostgreSQL. It does not equal 0, empty string, or spaces. So no equality operators works with NULL values.

`select null = null;`

It is but we don't get any results.

Instead of `=` or `!=` we should use `is` or `is not` statements.

`select null is null;`

| ?column? |
| --- |
| true |

Now I change my query to tested null values via the `is` statement and also use the equality operator to test datetime object if there

```
select * from product_history h1
join product_history h2 on h1.so_line_id = h2.so_line_id and h2.id != h1.id
and
(
(h1.end_date = h2.end_date)
OR
(h1.end_date is null and h2.end_date is null)
)
where h1.so_line_id = 4040;
```

Comment: The IS is a part of the <null predicate>, it's not a statement.